# How to trigger aboutToQuit signal manually in PySide

Tags: qt, pyside, gevent

I'm trying to create a gevent-supported PySide main event loop, based on [someone else's code](https://github.com/tmc/pyqt-by-example/commit/b5d6c61daaa4d2321efe89679b1687e85892460a). The following code is using original `.exec_()` method and running correctly:

```
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyGuiClass()
    win.ui.show()

    def on_exit(): 
        print "bye..."

    app.aboutToQuit.connect(on_exit)
    app.exec_()
```

When I click the `X` button in the main window, `on_exit()` function is called and `bye...` string is printed to the console as well.

For the Gevent support, I needed to insert a `gevent.sleep(0.01)` somewhere inside `app.exec_()` loop, so I defined the following function:

```
def wait_app(app):
    app_is_running = True
    while app_is_running:
        app.processEvents()
        gevent.sleep(0.01)
```

and then changed the original code as follows:

```
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyGuiClass()
    win.ui.show()

    def on_exit(): 
        print "bye..."

    app.aboutToQuit.connect(on_exit)
    wait_app(app)
```

Then the Gui application runs perfectly as before, and Gevent based greenlets work in parallel as expected.

Only problem is that when I click the `X` button on the main window, the Qt application terminates (the window is closed) but the `on_exit()` function is not called, thus remaining greenlets are left working. How can I manually detect if main window's `X` button's click event via `QtGui.QApplication()` (the `app`) object?

## Edit

Considering the suggestion in the accepted answer, the working implementation is as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    import gevent
    def gevent_loop():
        gevent.sleep(0.01)
        timer.start(0)
    timer.timeout.connect(gevent_loop)
    timer.start(0)

    win = test()
    win.ui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

## Edit 2

Here is an example application: https://github.com/ceremcem/weighing-machine-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QCoreApplication::exec()` method itself is responsible for emitting the `aboutToQuit` signal (at least, as of Qt 4.x). Since you are bypassing `exec()` with your own simple event loop, this signal is never emitted.

Rather than re-implement `exec()`, the `QCoreApplication` [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html) recommends a different approach:

> To make your application perform idle processing (i.e. executing a special function whenever there are no pending events), use a QTimer with 0 timeout.

I don't know anything about Gevent, but you could try using a timer to trigger a call to `gevent.sleep(0.01)` through each run through the event loop. That way, you can be sure that you aren't circumventing any built-in behaviors implemented by `exec()`.